# Using ansible loop until with stdout_lines

Tags: ansible

I am trying to use ansible loop until the condition is met.
I can use `until` if the output is only single line, however if the output is multiple lines, I will need to use `stdout_lines` but fail to do so.

If output is single line:

```
- name: check on sync status
  shell: some command
  register: sync_status
  until: sync_status.stdout == 'SSUS'
```

If output is multiple lines, then I try to use `stdout_lines`

```
- name: check on sync status
  shell: some command 
  register: sync_status
  until: item.stdout_lines == 'SSUS'
  with_items: "{{ sync_status }}"
```

but I got variable undefined:

```
fatal: [xxxxxxx]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "'sync_status' is undefined"
}
```

I don't want to do it on seperate task because then the sync_status is registered on previous task  , and I will be comparing the old status instead of the current status.

Kindly assist.

Comment: You can't both *loop* and *register* the same variable.

Comment: The use case is not clear. What do you want to do when the condition is not met?

Comment: basically this task is just to check the status, once the condition is met I will just proceed to next task.

Answer (score 1):

For example, given the file and the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat test.txt 
XX

shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - ansible.builtin.command:
        cmd: cat test.txt
      register: sync_status
      until: sync_status.stdout == 'SSUS'
```

the task will fail

```yaml
TASK [ansible.builtin.command] ********************************************
FAILED - RETRYING: ansible.builtin.command (3 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: ansible.builtin.command (2 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: ansible.builtin.command (1 retries left).
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=true 
  attempts: 3
  cmd:
  - cat
  - test.txt
  delta: '0:00:00.003479'
  end: '2021-06-16 07:27:19.927499'
  rc: 0
  start: '2021-06-16 07:27:19.924020'
  stderr: ''
  stderr_lines: <omitted>
  stdout: XX
  stdout_lines: <omitted>
```

But, if you insert the string "SSUS" into the file before or during the testing the task will succeed, e.g.

```yaml
TASK [ansible.builtin.command] ********************************************
FAILED - RETRYING: ansible.builtin.command (3 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: ansible.builtin.command (2 retries left).
changed: [localhost]
```

Fit the [parameters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#retrying-a-task-until-a-condition-is-met) to your needs.

---

Q: *"**If the output is multiple lines, I will need to use stdout_lines.**"*

A: Test the presence of the string in the list, e.g.

```yaml
    - ansible.builtin.command:
        cmd: cat test.txt
      register: sync_status
      until: "'SSUS' in sync_status.stdout_lines"
```

Comment: Hi, for example, there are multiple lines, some with SSUS, some with PAIR. My conditions is to make sure  all lines are met , not just some of the lines consist the keyword